# Real time OCR lag

Tags: python, ocr, easyocr

im trying to capture position of license plate with webcam feed using YOLOv4 tiny then input the result to easyOCR to extract the characters. The detection works well in real time, however when i apply the OCR the webcam stream become really laggy. Is there anyway i can improve this code to make it make it less laggy?

my YOLOv4 detection

```
#detection
while 1:
    #_, pre_img = cap.read()
    #pre_img= cv2.resize(pre_img, (640, 480))
    _, img = cap.read()
    #img = cv2.flip(pre_img,1)
    hight, width, _ = img.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1 / 255, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False)

    net.setInput(blob)

    output_layers_name = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()

    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_name)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            score = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(score)
            confidence = score[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.7:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * hight)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * hight)
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, .5, .4)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            score = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(score)
            confidence = score[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * hight)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * hight)

                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, .8, .4)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(boxes), 3))
    if len(indexes) > 0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i], 2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
           # detection= cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            detected_image = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y + 400), font, 2, color, 2)
            #print(detected_image)
            cv2.imshow('detection',detected_image)

            cv2.imwrite('lp5.jpg',detected_image)
            cropped_image = cv2.imread('lp5.jpg')
            cv2.waitKey(5000)
            print("system is waiting")
            result = OCR(cropped_image)
            print(result)
```

easy OCR function

```
def OCR(cropped_image):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)  # what the reader expect from  the image
    result = reader.readtext(cropped_image)
    text = ''
    for result in result:
        text += result[1] + ' '

    spliced = (remove(text))
    return spliced
```

Comment: When you say "the detection works well in real time", what do you mean?  The cam is going to deliver 30 frames a second.  Do you finish your processing in 33ms?

Comment: @TimRoberts hi , what i mean is that the detection is able to achieve good fps when i run in using my webcam feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points.

1. `cv2.waitKey(5000)` in your loop causes some delay even though you keep pressing a key. So remove it if you are not debugging.
2. You are saving a detected region into a JPEG image file and loading it each time. So pass the region(Numpy array) on the OCR module directly.
3. EasyOCR is a DNN model based on ResNet, but you are not using a GPU(`gpu=False`). So use GPU.(See this [benchmark](https://medium.com/swlh/ocr-engine-comparison-tesseract-vs-easyocr-729be893d3ae) by Liao.)
4. You are creating an `easyocr.Reader` instance each time in a loop. Creating it requires to load and initialize a DNN model. This is a huge workload causing the major bottleneck. So create only single instance before the loop and reuse it inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially saying "the `while` loop must be fast."
And of course the OCR() call is a bit slow.
Ok, good.

Don't call OCR() from within the loop.

Rather, enqueue a request,
and let another thread / process / host
worry about the OCR computation,
while the loop quickly continues
upon its merry way.

You could use a threaded [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html),
or a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html),
or blast it over to RabbitMQ or Kafka.
The simplest approach would be to
simply overwrite `/tmp/cropped_image.png`
within the loop,
and have another process notice such
updates and (slowly) call OCR(),
appending the results to a log file.

There might be a couple of updates
to the image file while a single
OCR call is in progress, and that's fine.
The two are decoupled from one another,
each progressing at their own pace.
Downside of a queue would be OCR
sometimes falling behind -- you actually
*want* to shed load by skipping some
(redundant) cropped images.

---

The two are racing, and that's fine.
But take care to do things in atomic
fashion -- you wouldn't want to OCR
an image that starts with one frame
and ends with part of a subsequent
frame.
Write to a temp file and, after close(),
use `os.rename()` to atomically
make those pixels available under
the name that the OCR daemon
will read from.
Once it has a file descriptor
open for read, it will have no
problem reading to EOF without
interference, the kernel takes
care of that for us.

Comment: hi thankyou so much, i will try to apply this

Comment: hi, can you give me example on how i can apply the queue or subprocess into my code? i have a hard time understanding the concept

Comment: Let `program1.py` be the OP code you offered above, but using a fast "write to /tmp/cropped_image.png" rather than "slow OCR call". Let `program2.py` be a `while` loop that consults `p.stat().st_mtime`, and calls OCR() whenever that image timestamp changes. Run both programs simultaneously in separate Terminal windows. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat (Or read and understand the `subprocess` docs. As my post suggested, that would be more work, likely more work than you'd care to do.)